# Parsing an IPAddress taken from a textfile

Tags: c#, asp.net, parsing, text, ip-address

Slight issue here. I am trying to use IPAddress.Parse( text ) where the text has been taken from a .txt file.

For reasons I cannot begin to fathom it catches this error.
"SystemFormatException: An invalid IPAddress was specified...line 32"

The strange thing is
text = `127.0.0.1` which to my knowledge should parse...

Here is the relevant code:

```
string appData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
string folder = @"/cube";
string file = @"/info.txt";

try
{
    string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(appData + folder + file);
    text = text.Replace("\n", "");
    Logs.store(text);

    IP = IPAddress.Parse(text);
    Logs.store("IP -> " + IP.ToString());
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    setupRequired = true;
    Logs.store("Setup required..");
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a character that you cannot see, '\r'.  Use Environment.NewLine instead of "\n".

Comment: Instead of replacing specific whitespace characters explicitly, try something like `string.Trim()` to remove any system-recognized leading or trailing whitespace: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx

Comment: Changed line text = text.Replace... to David's text = text.Trim()
Thanks Again!